# Group Dataframe entries based on values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is a rather common thing to do in finance applications, but I don't quite know how to do it efficiently.
Suppose I have a dataframe of returns like so:

```
  IBM INTC MSFT
1 0.1  0.2  0.3
2 -0.5 0.1 -0.1
3 -0.1 0.2  0.3
```

and another Dataframe of indices formed based on some other variable(e.g. momentum, earning...)

```
  IBM INTC MSFT
1   1   1    2
2   1   2    1
3   2   1    1
```

So for row 1, I have grouped IBM and INTC as group 1, and MSFT as group 2. Similarly, in row 2, I have grouped IBM as group 1, and MSFT and INTC as group 2. I would like to perform calculations such as taking average return across different groups.

I have tried to use groupby, but it seems like groupby works only within one dataframe and is based on columns. How should I structure my data structure to utilize groupby? I saw from the documentation, first argument of groupby function can actually be a mapping function. I couldn't find any examples on this though.

Comment: No. For row 2 you have grouped IBM and MSFT as group 1 and INTC as group2. It this what you intended to say ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to do it with stacked records (so that we don't have to bother groupby for each row). Basically, you need to do two groupby, first on `timestamp index` (it's integer index `1, 2, 3` here in this case) and then another inner groupby based on your reference variable, say `momentum`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# ==================================================
print(df1)


   IBM  INTC  MSFT
1  0.1   0.2   0.3
2 -0.5   0.1  -0.1
3 -0.1   0.2   0.3

print(df2)

   IBM  INTC  MSFT
1    1     1     2
2    1     2     1
3    2     1     1


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['return'] = df1.stack()
df['ref'] = df2.stack()

print(df)

        return  ref
1 IBM      0.1    1
  INTC     0.2    1
  MSFT     0.3    2
2 IBM     -0.5    1
  INTC     0.1    2
  MSFT    -0.1    1
3 IBM     -0.1    2
  INTC     0.2    1
  MSFT     0.3    1

# processing
# ==================================================

df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: g.groupby('ref').agg(np.mean))

       return
  ref        
1 1      0.15
  2      0.30
2 1     -0.30
  2      0.10
3 1      0.25
  2     -0.10
```